# What is the syntax for extending a 4D matrix by adding a channel, in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix, octave

What is the Matlab syntax to make a [X, Y, Z, N] matrix into a [X, Y, Z+1, N] matrix by adding a [X, Y ,N] matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to check the `cat()` command from the Help [here](http://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cat.html).